# How to predict with Affinity Propagation in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am trying to train and predict with an affinity propagation model for the first time.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation

data = np.array([[0.1,0.1,0.4], [0.0, 0.1, 0.5], [0.7,0.5,0.2]])

affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity="euclidean", damping=0.7, random_state=0)
affprop.fit(data)

data_2 = np.array([[0.1,0.1], [0.0, 0.1], [0.7,0.5]])

affprop.predict(data_2)
```

However when I run this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: X has 2 features, but AffinityPropagation is expecting 3 features as input.
```

Am I misunderstanding how affinity propagation works with prediction? I want to be able to feed my trained model new data. Does the number of dimensions (i.e. length of each sub-list) need to be the same as the trained data?

Comment: Yes the size of each sublist should be the same, I think you're getting mixed up with the number of examples (samples - number of sublists) and the dimension (number of features - length of each sublist) of each example. You're training the model with 3 samples with 3 features. So you need to pass an array with any number of samples, but each must contain 3 features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element in `data_2` should be of the same shape as each element in `data_1` here **(3,1)**

Either `data_2 = np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.0, 0.1, 0.2], [0.7, 0.5, 0.25]])`
or `data_2 = np.array([[0.1,0.1, 0.1]])` would work.

You're trying to predict the cluster that your new data belongs to, so it must lies in the same n-dimensional space.